# php cannot redeclare _autoload()

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I getting more indepth with php and I am creating my own mini mvc framework to learn OOP.

I have a .htaccess file that redirects everything to the index.php. In the index.php I include a file called boootstrap.php to parse the url and load the class php file.

Now that I am adding ActiveRecord http://www.phpactiverecord.org to add database access. I get the error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class AutoLoader in /home/i554246/public_html/mvc/lib/Autoloader.php on line 4

I am not sure how to stop the conflict.

index.php:

```
include(MVC_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Bootstrap.php')
include(MVC_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'activerecord/ActiveRecord.php');
```

autoloader.php which is included in bootstrap.php

```
<?php

class AutoLoader
{
    public static function Load($Class)
    {
        $File = BASEDIR.$Class.'.php';

        if(is_readable($File))
        {
            require($File);
        }
        else
        {
            die('Requested module "'.$Class.'" is missing. Execution stopped.');
        }
   }
}

spl_autoload_register('AutoLoader::Load');
```

ActiveRecord.php

```
if (!defined('PHP_ACTIVERECORD_AUTOLOAD_DISABLE'))
    spl_autoload_register('activerecord_autoload',false,PHP_ACTIVERECORD_AUTOLOAD_PREPEND);

function activerecord_autoload($class_name)
{
    $path = ActiveRecord\Config::instance()->get_model_directory();
    $root = realpath(isset($path) ? $path : '.');

    if (($namespaces = ActiveRecord\get_namespaces($class_name)))
    {
        $class_name = array_pop($namespaces);
        $directories = array();

        foreach ($namespaces as $directory)
            $directories[] = $directory;

        $root .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode($directories, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    }

    $file = "$root/$class_name.php";

    if (file_exists($file))
        require $file;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps change

```
if (file_exists($file))
    require $file;
```

to

```
if (file_exists($file))
    require_once($file);
```

Comment: If possible I would not like to change anything the ActiveRecord.php as it is third party and might lead to upgrade issues. Would there be another way?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm inclined to agree with [Nanne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/546999/nanne) that your next step should be to debug the stack. I think you need a precise account of the order in which things are happening. Also take Nanne's advice on namespaces -- even if there isn't a namespace conflict at the root of this problem, the extra bit of discipline will help you to rule out red herrings.

Answer (score 1):

You either try to include a file twice (you might want to use `require_once`) or you have 2 classes (one from a library you use?) with that same name.

if There seem to be 2 classes called `AutoLoader`, you might want to look into namespaces. I can't recall phpactiverecord having a class called that, but as you might use several libraries you were bound to run into this.

The best way would be to put your own autoloader class in a `namespace`. Make sure you keep all your calls correct, so calls to the autoloader should have `\yournamespace\` in front of it, and calls inside the autoloader might need  prepending a `\` to (like `\Exception` for instance)

Comment: If I load ActiceRecord.php first I it has an issue with the Fatal error: Cannot redeclare activerecord_autoload() (previously declared in /home/i554246/public_html/mvc/lib/activerecord/ActiveRecord.php:28) in /home/i554246/public_html/mvc/lib/activerecord/ActiveRecord.php on line 48

Comment: Well, activerecord doesn't have this problem in its own, so there must be something else going on. You are probably including that file twice, maybe both autoloaders include it? I would advice you to just debug it: put something that logs the stacktrace in that doubly called file, and then check what happens: now you know what parts of the code load that file. the second time you'll get the error, but you can then go on and prevent it being loaded twice.

Comment: Thanks, I added the require_once to ActiveRecord.php and the error moved onto the next included and complained about that class. Again I added require_once to that and the error moved again to the next include and could not redeclare that class. It seems to reload the index.php where all the includes are. Very strange, only happens when I included the ActiveRecords.

Comment: Maybe the activerecord autoloader triggers on the same requests as your own autoloader? so it loads your autoloader twice? or everything that gets autoloaded gets autoloded twice?

Comment: yes, think so, all new to me so I am a bit confused. It seems to happen with this line that I have in the index.php under the includes $Bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

Comment: Well, as I said, you should just keep the error in for now, and add some logging! Use `error_log` and `debug_backtrace` to find out what your code does when, and then you can see why and how some file is included twice.

Answer (score 1):

PHP-ActiveRecord doesn't have any `AutoLoader` class. What happens here I guess, is that you have two loaders that are loading the file.

Since it's PSR-0 compliant, you can load it using your own loading utility (assuming it's embracing that convention). If you do so just disable PHP-AR autoloading utility.

```
define('PHP_ACTIVERECORD_AUTOLOAD_DISABLE', true);
```

The vanilla loader is moslty useful for finding model classes which won't be needed if you're putting them in their own namespace. As your framework might not follow PHP-AR convention regarding where the models are, it seems correct to disable that autoloader.

Check that example of PHP-AR integration with lithium framework: [li3_activerecord](https://github.com/greut/li3_activerecord/blob/qoqa/config/bootstrap.php)

Answer (score 0):

I moved the line

```
$Bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
```

under the

```
include(MVC_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Bootstrap.php'); 
include(MVC_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Controller.php');
```

but above

```
require_once 'lib/activerecord/ActiveRecord.php'; the ActiveRecord seemed to want to load it again
```